# 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: U2A2_SommeElements, sommePairs

Tags: actionscript-3

So I started a to edit a program (it us given to us half empty and we have to add code to it) in my computer course the other day and I keep getting this error and can't find what's wrong. Sorry about the french variables and comments ahead of time. Any comments that are a waste of space were already there when I got the code.

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class U2A2_SommeElements extends MovieClip {

  var affichage:String="";      //variable pour stocker une liste de tous les éléments du tableau.
  var sommeMessage:String="";   //variable pour stocker le message indicant si la somme est pour 
                                //tous les entiers, les pairs ou les impairs.
  var somme:int;                //variable pour stocker la somme calculée.

  // Déclarer un tableau servant à stocker un nombre inconnu d'éléments.
  var mesEntiers:Array = new Array();


  // ****************************************************************
  // Fonction constructeur de la classe.
  public function U2A2_SommeElements() 
  {

    // Ajouter écouteur d'événement pour réagir à clic sur btnAjouter.
    btnAjouter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ajouter);

    // Ajouter écouteur d'événement pour réagir à clic sur btnSupprimer.
    btnSupprimer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, supprimer);

    // Ajouter écouteur d'événement pour réagir à clic sur btnAfficher.
    btnAfficher.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, afficher);

    // Ajouter écouteur d'événement pour réagir à clic sur btnSommeTotale.
    btnTotale.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sommeTotale);

    // Ajouter écouteur d'événement pour réagir à clic sur btnPairs.
    btnPairs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sommePairs);

    // Ajouter écouteur d'événement pour réagir à clic sur btnImpairs.
    btnImpairs.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, sommeImpairs);

    // Taper l'instruction include.
    include "U2A2_Elements.as"

  } // Fin fonction constructeur



  // ****************************************************************
  // Fonction pour réagir à un clic sur btnAjouter.
  function ajouter(event:MouseEvent):void 
  {
    //Declare variables to hold the input (integer) value
    var entierSaisi:String;
    var entier:int;

    // Lire le texte du champ de saisie et le stocker dans une variable String.
    entierSaisi=(txtEntier.text);

    // Convertir la chaîne de caractères saisie (String) en un entier (int).
    entier=int(entierSaisi);

    // Ajouter le nouvel entier à la fin du tableau.
    mesEntiers.push(entier);

  } // Fin fonction ajouter.



  // ****************************************************************
  // Fonction pour réagir à un clic sur btnSupprimer.
  function supprimer(event:MouseEvent):void 
  {

    // Compose cette fonction visant à supprimer des éléments du tableau.
    entierSaisi=(txtEntier.text);
    entier=int(entierSaisi);

    entier =(entier.indexOf(entierSaisi.text));

    if (entier != -1)
    {
        for (var i=entier; i <entier.length; i++)
        {
            entier[i] = entier[i+1];
        }
        entier.pop();
    }


  } // Fin fonction supprimer.



  // ****************************************************************
  // Fonction pour réagir à un clic sur btnAfficher.
  function afficher(event:MouseEvent):void 
  {

    // Compose cette fonction visant à afficher tous les éléments du tableau.


  } //Fin fonction afficher.



  // ****************************************************************
  // Fonction pour réagir à un clic sur btnSommeTotale.
  function sommeTotale(event:MouseEvent):void 
  {
    var sommeTotale:int;
    affichage="";

    for (var i=0; i<mesEntiers.length; i++)
    {
      sommeTotale = sommeTotale + mesEntiers[i];
      affichage = affichage + ("Element #" + i + " = " + mesEntiers[i] + "\n");
    }

    somme=sommeTotale;
    sommeMessage="\nLa somme de TOUS les entiers est: ";
    txtSortie.text = affichage + sommeMessage + somme;

  } // Fin fonction sommeTotale.



  // ****************************************************************
  // Fonction pour réagir à un clic sur btnSommeImpairs.
  function sommeImpairs(event:MouseEvent):void 
  {

    //Compose cette fonction visant à:
    //calculer la somme de entiers impairs du tableau et
    //afficher une liste de ces éléments et leur somme.
    var intImpairs:int;

    for (var i=0; i<mesEntiers.length; i++)
    {
        var entier:int = mesEntiers[i];
        if (someNumber%2 != 0)
        {
        intImpairs = mesEntiers[i]
        }
      sommeImpairs = sommeImpairs + intImpairs;
      affichage = affichage + ("Element #" + i + " = " + mesEntiers[i] + "\n");
    }

}


  } // Fin fonction sommeImpairs.



  // ****************************************************************
  // Fonction pour réagir à un clic sur btnSommePairs.
  function sommePairs(event:MouseEvent):void
  {

    // Compose cette fonction visant à:
    //        calculer la somme de entiers pairs du tableau et
    //        afficher une liste de ces éléments et leur somme.


  } // Fin fonction sommePairs.



// Fin classe.

// Fin paquetage.
}
```

Comment: there other classes with the same names it's pretty straight forward. It's also very common to get into those problems when not using packages. Here that class has an empty package scope. Add more scope to your project by using packages.

Comment: @BotMaster Looks like an extra bracket to me...

Comment: you are probably right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an extra bracket after `sommeImpairs()` and before `sommePairs()`:

```
function sommeImpairs(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
    /* ... */
}
} // Fin fonction sommeImpairs. (ERROR: This closes U2A2_SommeElements class)

function sommePairs(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    /* ... */
}
```

This ends your class prematurely, expositing `sommePairs()` outside of the class.

Comment: Thanks! That solved that problem. I think the worst part is that I downloaded the files that I had to edit and that was already there.